Removed question was before closed by moderator
Is it possible to know why this question was removed?
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/452793/how-do-you-build-a-high-availability-horizontally-scaling-application
I was looking for something in StackExchange Software engineering and found that one, left it open in a different tab after I found it interesting. before it was not accepting answers but now deleted. I read some of the contents and that's why I'm asking why got deleted not just closed?
Thanks,

It seems you could have prevented the automatic deletion by upvoting either the question or the existing answer.

I upvoted the question @DocBrown :/

Strange, I can see the question has only one upvote and one downvote, and the upvote was from me.

AFAIK I did, but if you cannot see that, then I'm wrong, is it possible to reopen it? @DocBrown

The question has currently two undelete votes (one from me). If a 3rd high rep member will vote for undeletion, it will be reopened. This is a democratic process, I have no further influence on it.

Thanks @DocBrown

It was automatically deleted by the community bot based on several criteria, which you can read about here:

The Community user deleted my question! What gives 

Specifically, look under the section for questions 9 days old.
